# ApplicationDbContext - where it belongs in project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, projects-and-solutions

I want to use one (EF) context file in my mvc 5 app and I want to use asp identity.

I have a few projects in solution DAL, GUI and WebAPI.

I want to just move `ApplicationDbContext` in DAL assembly and remove EF completly from my UI project.

What you do with `ApplicationDbContext` and asp identity when you start your new projects?

Do you leave it in UI layer or you moving it to data layer?

I really don't have any experienced dev to ask I hope it will not be downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Separating Identity:

Separating Identity from the UI is much trickier. Here, Microsoft has entangled them so closely that I would recommend leaving it until you understand Identity, EF, and the Repository Pattern at an expert level.

But, in case you are interested in separating Identity from the UI Level, here is a great **[resource from Dino Esposito](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745860.aspx)**

---

- Notice the reference to `ApplicationDbContext` in your Account Controller's Constructor:

  ```
  public AccountController()
      : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>
                           (new ApplicationDbContext())))
  ```

This can easily be a reference to a Context in your DAL.

- you will have great difficulty using a Repo over a context. That would require re-writing the `UserManager` which I highly doubt you want to do.
- You can create a child that inherits from `ApplicationDbContext` and is abstracted with an Interface

:

```
public class UserIdentityContext : ApplicationDbContext, IUserIdentityContext
```

Now you can use Ninject to bind your Account Controller to an Abstract Pattern

```
public AccountController()
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>
                         (IUserIdentityContext identityContext)))
```

But none of these moves allow you to remove EF assemblies from your UI Project. Here Microsoft bound the Data and UI elements too closely. You would have to re-write the Account Controller.

It's an issue they are dealing with and will probably improve on greatly in a ***MVC 6*** / ***Identity 3***

Comment: All my entities in dal project also comtain repository for each of them. I use repository and ninject. Inside dal I have one DbContext class with all entities. Problem is mvc project that has user entity and identity ApplicationDbContext and I want it to be part of dbcontext inside dal project so I can have all entities in one place. I think this is how real mvc project are made. I hope I am right? I want to know is this what I want overhead? What you do when you start project that use identity, are you removing it in separate project or what?

Comment: @1110, I added a followup to my answer. You can definitely reference a Context from your DAL in the Account Controller. You will have great difficulty referencing a REPO without re-writing the `UserManager`class. On the other hand, as I demonstrate, you can use Ninject to bind a new Context that inherits from your `ApplicationDbContext` and an Interface. But none of these moves allow you to remove EF assemblies from your UI Project. Here Microsoft bound the Data and UI elements too closely. You would have to re-write the Account Controller.

Comment: @1110, In answer to your question, I move my DBContext for Identity to my DAL, but I leave all else the same -- Almost, I use NInject to bind a version of Context that inherits from DBContext. But for now, I leave all else alone. I don't want to re-create the wheel.

Answer (score 7):

I presume you're talking about Entity Framework's DbContext? If so then you're right to keep this in your DAL assembly.

Moving it and changing your namespace is all you need to do.

Comment: Yes I have meant in EF context. But just moving it and changing namespace doesn't allow me to remove EF reference from GUI assembly.

Comment: @1110 then you're still using some other EF classes in your GUI; you need to find them and move that code into your DAL assembly as well.

Comment: What have you moved, and what is still referencing EF?  Go to the reference and right-click and `find code dependent on module`.  Also, I would also extract my own interface as `IMyContext`, etc, and use that as the DI point, not the DbContext class, to remove that last direct dependency on the context classes.

Comment: Whole account controller reference EF. I also wonder if I move all like I want and If I update identity later to some new version via nuget will it be possible anyway.

Comment: See my answer below, but if you want your ApplicationUser to inherit from IdentityUser, you have to reference that EF assembly. It should be possible to instead reference IUser, but it will be a bit more complicated to complete.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and not that difficult to remove the ApplicationDbContext from your ui project. The most complete way is to create a webapi project that will expose the functions of the IUserStore, or at least just the functions you need, and you won't need them all. The web api methods just delegate to the underlying entityframework, used in a DAL or not. Like (with a repository)

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("finduserbyid/{userId}")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
  {
     var verifiedUser = await this.UnitOfWork.ApplicationUserRepository.FindByIdAsync(userId);

     if (verifiedUser == null)
     {
        return NotFound();
     }

     return Ok(verifiedUser);
  }
```

Then create a new class in your ui project, or a utility project that implments IUserStore and calles the webapi for the data. I was able to do this in a day or so, not very difficult. Like this:

```
public class RemoteUserStore<T> : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
    , IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>
    , IUserLoginStore<ApplicationUser>
    , IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>
    , IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public RemoteUserStore(string identityServerUrl)
    {
        _appServerUrl = identityServerUrl;
    }

    private readonly string _appServerUrl;
    private string IdentityServerUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _appServerUrl;
        }
    }


    public async Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string url = string.Format("{0}/api/identity/createuser/{1}", IdentityServerUrl, user.Id);

        var userContent = MapApplicationUserToFormContent(user);
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, userContent);
    }

   //snip
}
```

You will not be able to eliminate a reference to entity framework however, as the UI will actually use the ApplicationUser with IdentityUser as a base class and it is defined in the microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework package